# How can we assign initial value in RTE for application layer interface?

Tags: autosar

when we are creating .arxml for application layer and that time we gave initial values for port interfaces. But that initial values are not getting when we create/generate RTE.

Comment: It may be the configuration issue check the init value section in AUTOSAR_TPS_SoftwareComponentTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Do you have different init-values for the sender and the receiver port? In that case (as far as I recall) the sender init-value is overriding the receiver init value.